# What is a word for two-person team?

Tags: word-request

While describing an all-women rally raid, I want to mention that participants compete by teams of two, but I believe there is a better / shorter word for that. Which would be best:

- As duos
- In pairs
- Anything with doubles / double?

Comment: Note that they compete _in teams of two_ not _by_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"**Pairs**" would be the most idiomatic term in this context, ie "*they compete in pairs*".

"Duo" isn't usually used in sports.

"Doubles" tends to be used where two pairs compete against one another, as in tennis.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!